# Can't inject into a static field in a test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, h2

I tried to test this. Notice it's an interface so I was going to test the class Spring writes for me (as an exercise, I'm learning testing)

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.List;

public interface RoleDao extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByAuthority(String authority);

    List<Role> findByAuthorityOrAuthority(String auth1, String auth2);
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    // toString()
}
```

Here's my test class:

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
class RoleDaoTest {
    static RoleDao roleDao;
    static final Role USER = new Role("USER");
    static final Role ADMIN = new Role("ADMIN");
    @Autowired
    /*could be public, doesn't matter */ void setRoleDao(RoleDao roleDao) {
        RoleDaoTest.roleDao = roleDao;
    }
    @BeforeAll
    static void addSampleRows() {
        roleDao.saveAll(List.of(USER, ADMIN));
    }
    @Test
    void findByAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthority("USER")).isEqualTo(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")).asList().contains(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

The `properties` file for tests (inside the test resource root):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

I get NPE, because nothing gets injected. Why?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pp.spring_bootstrap.dao.RoleDao.saveAll(java.lang.Iterable)" because "pp.spring_bootstrap.dao.RoleDaoTest.roleDao" is null
```

Can't I inject into `static` fields with setters? I thought it's the trick you use to inject into statics

Comment: Is there a reason why you actually need those fields to be static in the first place?

Comment: @Miro `@BeforeAll` has to be `static` so the field has to be `static` too

Comment: Would it then make sense to add the data into the db in `@BeforeEach` and clear it after each test in `@AfterEach`? 

That way you can also ensure that different tests won't cause the others to fail if the tests adds or removes any data.

Comment: @Miro it could make sense (though hardly in this particular case). But why doesn't my code work?

Comment: It is most likely because the `@Autowired` in the setter is executed after your class instance is created. But the `@BeforeAll` is called in the "static context" before the instance of your test class is created.

Comment: @Miro you're right. You could write it as an answer. Don't forget to include an alternative solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to make your code work. First one is to use `@BeforeEach` method, that does not require static signature and ensures that the needed rule is executed before each test case.

```
@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

@BeforeEach
void addSampleRows() {
    roleDao.saveAll(List.of(USER, ADMIN));
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `@TestInstance` annotation. The `@TestInstance` annotation in JUnit 5 is used to determine the lifecycle of test instances for the annotated test class. By default it is `PER_METHOD`. If you change it to `PER_CLASS` `@BeforeAll` won't need to be static anymore:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class RoleDaoTest {
```

A single instance of the test class will be created for all test methods. This way, you can use dependency injection in those methods without any issues.

Your class will look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class RoleDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    static final Role USER = new Role("USER");
    static final Role ADMIN = new Role("ADMIN");

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        roleDao.saveAll(List.of(USER, ADMIN));
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthority("USER")).isEqualTo(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

By using the `PER_CLASS` lifecycle `roleDao` is properly injected.
The `init()` method (which is now an instance method and not static, runs once before all test methods.
You can use dependency injection in `@BeforeAll` without any complications.
However, remember that the `PER_CLASS` lifecycle means all test methods share the same instance of the test class. This could potentially introduce side effects between test methods, so always make sure to reset any shared state in your `@BeforeEach` or `@AfterEach` methods if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! On the other hand, `PER_METHOD` was chosen as the default for good reasons. And, in this particular case, performing the same inserts before each method seems redundant

Comment: Well, the possibility to set it PER_CLASS is there for a reason as well :) Have you found another workaround for your problem already?